# Composite Functions Necessary to List All Variables

Tags: functions

For composite functions (in this case q), is it necessary to list all the variables of the inner functions? For example, in the line below Column[,
cant we just write q[z], or must we write q[z[x,y[x]]? Wouldn't it be really troublesome if our composite function has many layers?

```
y[x_] := x^2;
z[x_, y_] := y - x;
q[z_] := z^2;

Manipulate[
 {
  Column[
   {x, y[x], z[x, y[x]], q[z]}
   ]
  },
 {x, 1, 2}
 ]
```

Comment: Could use a `With[]`: `With[{zz = z[x, y [x]]}, {zz, q[zz]}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ClearAll[x, y, z, q]
With[{y = x^2}, {z = y - x}, {q = z^2},
 Manipulate[Column[{x, y, z, q}], {x, 1, 2}]]
```